# Recover / reset SSH access without external monitor?

Tags: ssh, sd-card, password, reset

How can I regain SSH access if I:

- Have physical access to the device
- Do not have a way of plugging in an external monitor (or serial console)
- Was previously using SSH

Comment: I asked/answered this, because I didn't see my answer in any of the other questions, and I don't have enough reputation to post it on those.

Comment: How did you lose "SSH access"?

Comment: @Milliways I built a new PC and didn't save my old SSH key. Note: password-based authentication was disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

1. If you don't already have an SSH private/public keypair, generate one
2. Stick the SD card in the same machine as the SSH keypair
3. Append the public key (.pub extension) to the .ssh/authorize_keys file in home directory of the user you're trying to connect with - see "Appending", "Key location", and "Permissions" below for details.
4. Put SD card back in Pi and start it up
5. Connect using ssh -i (path to *private key*) (user)@(address)

If you were using SSH previously, you should be presented with a remote terminal. This just worked for me - enjoy.

## Appending

In Linux, you can use the following to append one file to another: `cat source_file >> detination_file`. For me, appending my SSH public key was as simple as: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /media/rootfs/home/pi/authorized_keys`; however, be sure to check the result - sometimes there's a line break missing, and you'll need to insert one manually.

## Key location

If you've got the SD card mounted on some other machine, you need to know two things:

1. Where the SD card is mounted
2. For the user you're trying to login with, the location on the SD card of the home directory (often /home/pi)

With these two, the location is: (SD card)/(path to home folder). For me on Pop OS!, this is /media/rootfs/home/pi/authorized_keys

## Permissions

- The `.ssh` directory on the SD card must have be rwx for user ONLY (700)
- The authorized key must be rw for user ONLY

You can run these commands to set permissions correctly:

```
cd /media/rootfs/home/pi
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: You can't *up-vote* your own answer, but you can vote to *accept* it. This is a good thing because it lets others know this is the answer that worked for you.